# How to open a stack of loot bags in one go?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Simple question really but it annoys me every time. Sometimes I buy 250 of the same bags, for example '[Heavy Moldy Bag](http://www.gw2db.com/items/67403-heavy-moldy-bag)' from the TP. When I have them all in my inventory I end up clicking 500 times on the icon to open all 250. Surely there must be a better way to do this?

Comment: I have a similar problem sometimes. I've considered suggesting a "use all" right-click function for containers and consumables, but I felt like it was such a niche problem that it wasn't worthwhile.

Comment: @Brian where did you make this suggestion? I'd like to upvote it, perhaps get it out of the niche.

Comment: It's totally not a niche problem, however, bag space is though! Would it be possible to implement a "open until bag full" option?

Comment: I hadn't actually suggested it, but I did just now. It's at https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/game/suggestions/Use-All-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time of writing there is no way known to me that let's you open a stack of those bags in one go.

The only way to automate this would be scripts or keyboard macros (if your keyboard supports those), but they are not allowed as per EULA.

Comment: For what it's worth, my mouse has triple-click (razer inferno) and it really helps with all the double-clicking in GW2.

Comment: How does triple-click help exactly?

Answer (score 2):

It's not just loot bags mind you, but also using salvage kits and consuming Essences of Luck :)

A simple Autohotkey script can save a lot of doubleclicking. For example, the following sends a double click when typing alt-d:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class ArenaNet_Dx_Window_Class
$!d::Click 2
```

While it's true that the use of scripts is not officially sanctioned, it's very unlikely a player will be banned for using a script that essentially redirects or remaps some input; not to mention that it would be very hard for the game to detect such scripts and prove a script was indeed used when you also have many keyboards and mouses with custom software that does essentially the same.

There is a popular script for example, called [Immersive Combat Mode](http://www.reddit.com/r/Guildwars2/comments/10s4s6/combat_mode_11/) which many players use for Guild Wars 2. The version 1.0 of this mod summarizes the situation as:

> ArenaNet are ok with mods that don't give an advantage over other players and don't impact others negatively

Comment: Technically they're okay with mods that give advantages too - like Eyefinity and arrow carts.